# How to get translation by key in component Angular2?

Tags: angular

I use [this library](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in Angular 2 for translations:

In my JSON file, I have word by key:

```
{
"delete_selected" : "Удалить выделенные",
}
```

Then inside component I try to fill object like as:

```
let obj = {
 title: <delete_selected>
};
```

How can I get translation by key word?

Comment: Why don't you just read the documentation? https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#api I've never used that library, and it took me literally 15 seconds to find the answer.

Comment: I read, but there is only one way, using observable, that is not convenient

Comment: It's only inconvenient if you don't understand how to use observables. But then all of angular will be inconvenient. translations need to be loaded. Loading is asynchronous. So observables are needed.

Comment: Trying to avoid observables in Angular 2+ will make your life very difficult.

Comment: Note that there is an instant method, also documented, that returns the currnt value, synchronously.

Comment: I know how to use observables. but see my question

Comment: I've seen your question. And I don't understand what the problem is. You subscribe to the observable, and when you get the translation, you create your object with that translation. As in any other use of an observable. I know observables are hard to grasp. I've suffered, and am still suffering, but you shouldn't reject their use. You should instead learn how they work.

Comment: Problem is that It returns me: login_step_1:"login_step_1"... without translations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used this library, but I'm 90% sure this will do the trick :

```cs
translate.get('delete_selected').subscribe((res: string) => {
    console.log(res);
    //=> '"Удалить выделенные"'
});
```

Comment: And how to fill this object using observable: `let obj = {
 title: <delete_selected>
};`?

Comment: `translate.get(...).subscribe(res => { let obj = { title: res }; ... })`.

Comment: But if I need to fill object of array? `this.tabs = {
      1: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_1'), sent: false, id: 1},
      2: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_2'), sent: false, id: 2},
      3: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_3'), sent: false, id: 3},
      4: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_4'), sent: false, id: 4},
      5: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_5'), sent: false, id: 5},
      6: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_6'), sent: false, id: 6},
      7: {title: this.translate.get('login_step_7'), sent: false, id: 7}
    };`

Comment: Once again, read the API doc. get() accepts an array of keys as argument, and returns an object containing all translations.

Comment: Sorry, I can not find this (:

Comment: get(key: string| **Array<string>**, interpolateParams?: Object): Observable<string| **Object** >: Gets the translated value of a key (or an array of keys) or the key if the value was not found. (emphasis mine)

Comment: Do you mean to pass an array string like as `['1','2']`? and it will return me an array?

Comment: No. it will return an Object. As the documentation shows. Why don't you try?

Comment: `this.translate.get(words).subscribe((res: Object) => {}`

Comment: It returns me: `login_step_1:"login_step_1"...`

Comment: Edit your question with the code you tried. The code you posted in the comment is not valid TypeScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `stream()` like:

```js
const item = '';
    
translate.stream('delete_selected').subscribe((res: string) => {
  this.item = res
});
```

The `get()` function returns the res once. `stream()` updates res every time the language is changed.